# Segmentation Fault when running ffmpeg+sdl program

Tags: c, ffmpeg, sdl

I started with [Dranger's tutorials](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) on building a video player using FFMPEG and SDL. The code tutorial4 compiles fine but when i run it i get a segmentation fault error. [here's the code for tutorial4.](http://pastebin.com/2VZef7zD)

I am using gcc

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

on Mac 10.10.3.

Here's GDB Backtrace:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x1813 of process 84136]
0x00007fff955d4432 in stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error ()
from /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x00007fff955d4432 in stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error ()
from /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
#1  0x000000010a2f1ee0 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000101341008 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
#3  0x00000000000005d0 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001013362e9 in RunThread () from /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
#5  0x00000001013362e2 in RunThread () from /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
#6  0x00007fff8d1d4268 in ?? () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
#7  0x0000000000006f23 in ?? ()
#8  0x000000010a2f2000 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000010a2f1f50 in ?? ()  
#10 0x00007fff8d1d41e5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Backtrace for another SIGSEGV:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x15eb of process 11453]
0x00000001012c9475 in av_log_format_line ()
from /usr/local/lib/libavutil.54.dylib
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000001012c9475 in av_log_format_line ()
from /usr/local/lib/libavutil.54.dylib
#1  0x00000001012f7338 in av_pix_fmt_descriptors ()
from /usr/local/lib/libavutil.54.dylib
#2  0x00000018012f7358 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000010a2f3010 in ?? ()
#4  0x000000010a2f2c10 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000010011d65a in ?? () from  /usr/local/lib/libavformat.56.dylib
#6  0x000000010a2f3900 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000018 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000018 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000010011d65a in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libavformat.56.dylib
#10 0x000000010a2f3900 in ?? ()
#11 0x910016d093cdc267 in ?? ()
#12 0x000000010a2f3eb0 in ?? ()
#13 0x00000001012c96e8 in av_log_default_callback ()
from /usr/local/lib/libavutil.54.dylib
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

The call to `SDL_WaitEvent` in main method is where these errors occur in my debugging.

```
for(;;) {
SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
switch(event.type) {
case FF_QUIT_EVENT:
case SDL_QUIT:
  is->quit = 1;
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
  break;
case FF_REFRESH_EVENT:
  video_refresh_timer(event.user.data1);
  break;
default:
  break;
 }
}
```

is this related to pthread library or sdl And how do i resolve it ?

Comment: Edit a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into the question.

Comment: @genpfault can u please tell me what other details do i need to add.

Comment: Take the code in the pastebin you link to, trim it down to the part(s) that crash (as determined by you and your debugger) and edit the result into the question.  I.e. a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).